# Approximating continuous functions in L^p by nice functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Problem: Let $X$ be a separable complete metric space and let the borel measure be inner and outer regular, and sigma finite, and $F$ a closed subset of $X$. Assume $f\in L^p(X)$ such that $f|_{F}=0$. Then show that there for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a continuous function $g\in L^p(X)$ such that $g|_{F}=0$ and such that $||f-g||_{L^p}<\epsilon$

We may use standard facts, otherwise if false, I must find a counterexample

Attempt:

I thought that since $F$ is closed, maybe I should consider $f_n(x)=\frac{d(x,F)}{n}$. or a variation. But I am stuck. $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ here.

Alternatively,functions in $L^p(X)$ can be approximated by continuous functions with compact support, so would need their support to be in $F^{c}$. But I don't know how to finish

What about $L^1$ or $L^2$?

Comment: It's important for what measure you impose on X. The answer is likely yes if it's inner and outer regular.

Comment: @LidingYao edited

Comment: Take a Dirac measure and f being 0 outside a fixed point. That would be a counterexample. You need more assumptions.

Comment: @LidingYao like under what conditions would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is too long for a comment, you can do this if you assume that $F$ is compact and $\mu$ is a Radon measure on $X$. From here, it may be possible to generalize to the general $F$ is closed case.

Furnish a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ with $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(\mu)$. Let $\{U_n\}$ be a decreasing sequence of open sets containing $F$ such that $\mu(U_n\setminus F) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Put $\rho_n = \frac{d(x,F)}{d(x,U_n^c) + d(x,F)}$. Then $\rho_n$ is continuous, and $0 \leq \rho_n \leq 1$, and $\rho_n = 1$ outside of $U_n$ and $\rho_n = 0$ on $K$. It follows that
$$\|f - \rho_nf_n\|_p^p = \int_{U_n^c}|f-f_n|^p\,d\mu + \int_{U_n\setminus F}|f-\rho_nf_n|^p\,d\mu$$
since $f$ and $\rho_n$ vanish on $F$. First, observe
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{U_n^c}|f-f_n|^p\,d\mu \leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\|f - f_n\|_p^p = 0.$$
Now we need to estimate $\int_{U_n\setminus F}|f-\rho_nf_n|^p\,d\mu$. For concision, label $h_n = \chi_{U_n\setminus F}$, so that $\int_{U_n\setminus F}|f-\rho_nf_n|^p\,d\mu = \|h_n(f_n- \rho_nf_n)\|_p^p$. Then
$$\|h_n(f - \rho_nf_n)\|_p \leq \|h_n\rho_n(f - f_n)\|_p + \|h_n(1-\rho_n)f\|_p \leq \|f - f_n\|_p + \|h_nf\|_p.$$
Since $f\in L^p(\mu)$ implies that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{U_n\setminus F} |f|^p \,d\mu = 0,$$
we conclude
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\|h_n(f - \rho_nf_n)\|_p = 0.$$
All of this is to say that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \|f - \rho_nf_n\|_p = 0,$$
and since clearly $\{\rho_nf_n\}$ is continuous and $\rho_nf_n|_F = 0$ for all $n$, this proves the claim.